# HTML / CSS - Menu not clickable if submenu is displayed

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu, clickable

The following menu works fine.
But as soon as I add the sub-menu then the menu items are not click-able any more (only the sub-menu items).

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul> 
    <li>
        <a href="site.php?page=home" class="active" > Home </a>
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="site.php?page=Account%20Summary" >Account Summary</a></li>
            <li><a href="site.php?page=Total%20Transaction" >Total Transaction</a></li>
            <li><a href="site.php?page=Claim%20Points" >Claim Points</a></li>
            <li><a href="site.php?page=Redeem%20Points" >Redeem Points</a></li>
            <li><a href="site.php?page=Profile" >Profile</a></li>
        </ul></li>    
    <li><a href="site.php?page=about" >         About Us    </a></li>
    <li><a href="site.php?page=restaurants" >   Restaurants </a></li>
    <li><a href="site.php?page=howItWorks" >    How It Works    </a></li>
    <li><a href="site.php?page=contact" >           Contact     </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to make the menu click-able even when the submenu is displayed?

Note: The sub-menu is only displayed if the user is logged in.

Comment: In order to tell exaclty what is going on you would need to let people see your css and javascript involved in the menu display.

Comment: Agreed. With plain HTML, this will work fine. I'd bet on it being a matter of an element being so positioned by CSS that part of it covers other links, hence preventing clicks (just hovering about with firebug or another dom-inspecting tool should demonstrate that, or temporarily adding `border: 1px solid red;` to make the edges visible to you), but that's a matter of the CSS so I can't know without seeing it.

Comment: Jon Hanna - Please post as an answer that I may accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with the help of Jon Hanna's comment:

I made a border around the elements in the menu.
The I saw the overlay and fixed it changing my CSS.